# Adwords: get stats data in different timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, google-ads-api

I'm using AdWords scripts to export performance of keywords and campaigns to our data pipeline. The funny thing is AdWords has -8:00 timezone due to our marketing colleague working from the US, while we keep everything in the pipeline in UTC (+0:00).

The data, I'm pretty sure, is for days shifted by 8 hours, which results in slightly inconsistent data.

On google groups I found [some hint of how to do it with HourOfDay](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/aYFEPdbcNLY), but that is [only available for campaigns](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report), not for keywords. Also, it seems I'd have to re-aggregate the data, instead of just setting "hey, just give me data in UTC timezone".

Before doing this overkill solution, I was wondering whether anyone has tackled this problem before us? Please share your insights, thank you!

**Relevant part of code:**

```
var range = ["20151201", "20151202"];
var keywordIter = AdWordsApp.keywords()
                            .withCondition("Cost > 0")
                            .forDateRange(range[0], range[1])
                            .get();
//then keywordIter.next(); and grab stats
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant parts of the script, and examples of the data your seeing.  Thanks.

Comment: Added code. The data is just numbers, it won't tell you anything. But this API is supposed to return the data for billing time zone and I couldn't find a way to make it return data in a different (UTC) timezone.